How to redirect an exact URL in ManifestV3 without matching nested pages?
When I specify the site's exact URL as urlFilter in a rule that should redirect to /questions page, it keeps redirecting every page of this site (e.g., profile, specific question, etc.) incorrectly.
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "https://stackoverflow.com",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  }
]

Tests
https://stackoverflow.com         | redirected (OK)   |
https://stackoverflow.com/another | redirected (FAIL) | expected: not redirect

How can I formulate in ManifestV3 to redirect only https://stackoverflow.com?

You should be able to use
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "https://stackoverflow.com/|",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  }
]

since a | dictates that no more characters may come after it.
See: chrome.declarativeNetRequest - URL filter syntax - Chrome Extension API

It was an interesting observation on my part that https://stackoverflow.com| didn't work. So, I assumed that the * character could be used to extend the syntax and that it is closed by default. It's a strange syntax, but in any case, with the /| suffix, I got the expected result. Thanks.

Note that this will erroneously match http://malware.com/https://stackoverflow.com/ unless you also add | at the beginning or use || without protocol to anchor the domain.

@woxxom you're awesome, thanks for bringing this to my attention! Luckily, in my use case, this would only result in the browser redirecting from the mentioned injected address to the actual so.com/questions. I find this Chrome-style-regex imitation really strange. I really thought the * would indicate that I can expect anything, but it works the exact opposite way. I don’t think it was a great idea to deviate from the standard, but I guess it’s something one can get used to.

This is AdBlock syntax, which is always a substring and * makes sense only if you use it between two parts: foo*bar.
